Clarification on Transforming from Discrete to Continuous Systems in Quantum Mechanics
In Quantum Mechanics: A Paradigms Approach by David H. McIntyre, a transformation from discrete systems to continuous ones is provided, outlined as follows:

$\vert\psi\rangle \rightarrow \psi(x)$

$\langle\psi\vert \rightarrow \psi(x)^*$

$\langle\vert\rangle \rightarrow \int^\infty_{-\infty}\ dx$

$\hat{A} \rightarrow A(x)$


While I find the transformations of 1, 2, and 4 to be clear, I am struggling to grasp the rationale behind the third point. It is commonly explained that since continuous systems involve integrals rather than sums, the normalization condition changes from the sum of probabilities equalling 1 to the integral equalling 1. Consequently, $|\psi(x)|^2 = p(x)^2$ is treated as a probability density rather than a probability itself.
However, this explanation leaves me uncertain. We desire both $\vert\psi\rangle$ and $p$ to satisfy Schrödinger's equation $(\hat{H}\vert\psi\rangle=i\hbar\partial_t\vert\psi\rangle)$, yet $\vert\psi\rangle \neq p$. Are we implying that both $p$ and $\vert\psi\rangle$ obey Schrödinger's equation? If so, how can we justify this?

You are abusing and misconstruing the mainstream Dirac notation. Review. How did you conclude your p obeys the TDSE?

Your 4. is magnificently sick: $\langle x|\hat A|y\rangle= A(x,y)$, so $\hat A =\int!! dx dy ~~|x\rangle A(x,y)\langle y| $.

@CosmasZachos consider a stern gerlach experiment, which is a discrete system, thus having $\vert\psi\rangle$ which follows TDSE. Now consider an infinite square well with position representation of energy eigenstates, $\langle x\vert E\rangle=\varphi(x)$ where $\vert E\rangle$ is energy eigenstate. Since it is a continuous state, $\varphi(x)$ is $p$ and follows TDSE.

@CosmasZachos To be clear, its not mine, but Mcintyre's. Second, it just means to write an operator in position eigen bases. For example $\hat p\rightarrow p(x)=-ih\partial_x$

I've no idea what you are trying to say, and I would not shadow-box with a book I'll probably never see... Overhaul your question to overcome the reader's sense that hardy anything you say makes any sense... Do you appreciate operators in discrete systems are finite matrices, and in continuous systems infinite matrices? This is the essence of Dirac's notation, where you hardly need specify whether your system is discrete or continuous, no?  In 4., you should then write $A_x$, not A(x); the mainstream expression is an integral kernel A(x,y). Reword and explain your question.

Are you concerned about the different dimensions of the basis kets between $\langle e_i|e_j\rangle= \delta_{ij}$ and  $\langle x|y\rangle= \delta(x-y)$ so $\Sigma_i |e_i\rangle \langle e_i|={\mathbb I}$ versus  $\int !! dx~ |x\rangle \langle x|={\mathbb I}$ ?

First of all, bra-ket notation is just as valid for continuous systems as it is for discrete ones. In a continuous system, $\vert\psi\rangle$ describes the physical state without any reference to external parameters. To describe the state in terms of its position dependence, one writes $\langle x\vert\psi\rangle = \psi(x)$, where $\psi(x)$ is now a function in $L^2(\Bbb C)$. The expression is to be read as the "projection" of the state $\vert\psi\rangle$ onto the "position space". A completely analoguous description exists for momentum space. Note that $\langle\psi\vert\phi\rangle$ simply means the scalar product of two vectors. If your vectors are functions in $L^2(\Bbb C)$, meaning states in a continuous quantum system, their scalar product in position space is given by
$$
\langle\psi\vert\phi\rangle = \int^\infty_{-\infty}\langle\psi\vert x\rangle\langle x\vert\phi\rangle dx = \int^\infty_{-\infty}\psi^\ast(x)\phi(x) dx
$$
where the first equality follows from the completeness relation for eigenvectors of a self-adjoint operator (which the $\vert x\rangle$ are):
$$
 \int^\infty_{-\infty}\vert x\rangle\langle x\vert dx = 1
$$
(Note that various normalization constants may appear in these formulas in the literature)
To answer your second question: The Schrödinger equation takes different forms depending on if you are in position or momentum space. $\vert\psi\rangle$ makes no reference as to which space you are in, so it is necessary to go from $\vert\psi\rangle$ to $\psi(x)$ (or $\psi(p)$) to solve the equation in a given framework.

To your last line: $\psi(x)$ is a continuous function, making its square a probability density. In discrete cases $\vert\psi\rangle$ is just a bunch of numbers (consider spin systems for example), making its square, the probability itself. Both of these are different things, but both are supposed to satisfy SE. Hence the question.

You get different Schrödinger equations in the discrete and continuous case. In the discrete case, your hamiltonian is simply a matrix, while in the continuous case, it is a differential operator. Both describe the energy of the system (Note that $E\rightarrow i\hbar\partial_t$) and have the same structure, so both are called Schrödinger equation.

"You get different Schrödinger equations in the discrete and continuous case". So, this is to be taken as a postulate, that there are indeed two different SE's, one for probability (discrete systems) and the other for probability density (continuous systems)?

The Schrödinger equation does not give you a probability. Probability comes from the square of the absolute value of a scalar product, which of course looks different in finite dimensional and infinite dimensional vector spaces.
